# Error Converting MySQL Query to SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Trying to convert below query into SQL, query works fine on MySQL. Problem seems to be the `GROUP BY` area. Even when I use just 1 `GROUP BY` field I get same error. Using query in InformaticaCloud.

**ERROR**

> "the FROM Config_21Cent WHERE resp_ind = 'Insurance' GROUP BY
>   resp_Ind;;] is empty in JDBC connection:
>   [jdbc:informatica:sqlserver://cbo-aps-inrpt03:1433;DatabaseName=SalesForce]."

```
    SELECT sum(Cast(Resp_Ins_Open_dol AS decimal(10,2))) as baltotal, 
           carrier_code, 
           carrier_name, 
           carrier_grouping, 
           collector_name, 
           dataset_loaded, 
           docnum, 
           envoy_payer_id, 
           loc, 
           market, 
           master_payor_grouping, 
           plan_class, 
           plan_name, 
           resp_ins, 
           resp_ind, 
           resp_payor_grouping, 
           Resp_Plan_Type, 
           rspphone, 
           state 
      FROM Config_21Cent 
     WHERE resp_ind = 'Insurance' 
  GROUP BY 
  (resp_ins + resp_payor_grouping + 
  carrier_code + state + Collector_Name);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your entire query isn't going to work.  The `group by` statement contains a single expression, the summation of a bunch of fields.  The `select` statement contains zillions of columns without aggregates.  Perhaps you intend for something like this:

```
select resp_ins,  resp_payor_grouping,  carrier_code,  state,  Collector_Name, 
       sum(Cast(Resp_Ins_Open_dol AS decimal(10,2))) as baltotal
from Config_21Cent
WHERE resp_ind = 'Insurance'
GROUP BY resp_ins,  resp_payor_grouping,  carrier_code,  state,  Collector_Name;
```

THis will work in both databases.

Comment: This does work but I'm still in need of those other field from the SELECT statement. The query does actually work fine in MySQL, though I understand it could be better. But how then can I get those other fields back into the SELECT as I understand from other post that SELECT must be a subset of the GROUP BY.

Comment: @user2451 . . . Which values do you want?  There are multiple rows in the aggregated query combining to form a single row in this result set.  Which rows should be providing the values for the other columns?  If the values are all the same, then just add them to the `group by` clause (and the `select` clause).

Answer (score 0):

The columns in `SELECT` statement must be a subset (not proper subset but subset) of columns in 'GROUP BY' statement. There is no such restriction on aggregates in `SELECT` statement though. There could be any number of aggregates; aggregates even on columns not in `GROUP BY` statement can be included.